# in the .NET MailMessage class, how do you remove an attachment?

Tags: c#, email-attachments, mailmessage

in the .NET MailMessage class, how do you remove an attachment?

We have modified the code on a project I am working on.  Part of the modifications seem to impact code that has not changed at all.

It would appear that now a part of the code that added attachments to email (using the "MailMessage" class) is failing because those email attachments are located on a secure server.

And so, as a test, it would be interesting to implement a piece of code that would remove the attachment upon a failure of the  SmtpClient Send (which passes a MailMessage class as a parameter).  If I am using .Attachments.Remove, it asks for an Attachment class.  Where and how do I assign this? 
[image]

Comment: `mail.Attachments.Clear()`

Comment: FYI, this class has nothing to do with C#. It's part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: how are you adding the attachments?

Comment: BTW, why do you want to remove the attachment? Are you going to keep the MailMessage around? It implements IDisposable, so should have Dispose called.

Answer (score 3):

`Remove` removes a specific item.  Use `mail.Attachments.Clear()` to remove *all* items.

Answer (score 3):

[Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachmentcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a collection, and, as every collection, has a `Clear` method as well a `Remove` method, but while `Remove` requires the single attachment to remove, the Clear acts on the whole Attachments collection removing any item present in it